# Change the width of the title in a panel

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a panel in my application, and the user can change its width. My problem is when the title is very long. I would like to crop the title by changing the width.
I have tried changind the width of the titleTextField by:
this.titleTextField.width = ...;
But it does not work.
Can any body help me?

Comment: What exactly is the current behavior when you resize? If you could provide your MXML layout, it might help us out :)

Answer (score 1):

Just crop the text:
use this function

```
private function cropText(str:String,w:int=-1):String{
    return (w != -1)?str.substr(0,w)+"...":str;
}
```

HOW TO USE:

**title = cropText("HELLOW WORLD",10);**

*OUTPUT:*

```
HELLOW WOR...
```

Hope it solves your problem

Comment: Hi Treby, thanks por your answer. But my problem is I don't know how to change the width of the component

Comment: do you mean the panel itself? or just the titlebar?